# Getting the latest status and date for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Working on SQL Server 2008 and I've been struggling with how to query this. Suppose I have the following table:

```
ID      Status      Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
A-1     Open        2018-01-01
A-1     Closed      2018-01-05
B-2     Closed      2018-02-01
B-2     Open        2018-02-06
B-2     Closed      2018-02-06
C-3     Closed      2018-03-01
C-3     Open        2018-03-03
C-3     Closed      2018-03-05
C-3     Open        2018-03-07
```

I want the results to be a table consisting of the ID and the status and date corresponding to the most recent activity for that ID. 
In the event that there is both an Open and Closed status on the same date, it should default to Closed. So, using the table above, the results should be:

```
ID      Status      Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
A-1     Closed      2018-01-05
B-2     Closed      2018-02-06
C-3     Open        2018-03-07
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER(PARTITION BY ID  -- latest date per ID, prefer 'Closed' over 'Open'
           ORDER BY Date DESC, Status) AS rn
   FROM tab
 )
SELECT * -- all columns but rn
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Why use a CTE instead of a simple subquery?

Comment: @DataWriter: Assuming you mean *Derived Table* by *subquery*, there's no difference between them. Most SQL Server users simply prefer CTEs, I personally use whatever fits best :-)

Comment: This does it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()`.  Often the most efficient method, though, is the more old-fashioned:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

This is particularly true if you have an index on `t(id, date)`.

Another method that can have better performance is `apply`.  This assumes that you have a table of `ids`:

```
select t.*
from ids cross apply
     (select top 1 t.*
      from t
      where t.id = ids.id
      order by t.date desc
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is always the **WITH TIES** option.

The CTE method tends to be ***slightly*** more performant.

```
 SELECT Top 1 with ties *
   From YourTable
   Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By Date Desc)
```